# Keyboard shortcut to select editor tab by number in XCode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to select a tab by ordinal number - like in browsers?  In particular something like `Control-1`/`Control-2` or `Alt-1`/`Alt-2` to select one of the two tabs presently displayed.

[image]

Note that even the `command-{` and `command-}` are not working for me.

Therefore even the less preferable approach of cycling through the tabs - as shown in a couple of questions such as this one https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85461/programmer-new-to-apple-how-to-efficiently-switch-between-files-in-xcode  - do not work.   So presently there is no way to switch tabs except by physically clicking on them.

A quite acceptable alternative would be a keyboard driven quick-list like  `Command-E` in `JetBrains` IDE's (intellij, pycharm, AppCode, etc)

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for toggling to the next tab is Control-Tab, which I find quite easy to remember. Also note that all keyboard shortcuts are user-configurable. That is _not_ answer to real question which is a great idea but the answer is no, there isn't. File an enhancement with Apple...!

Comment: @matt  That's good info - please make an answer

Comment: now with Xcode 12 the tabs are even better to use. But still no way to do ⌘+1 to select first tab, ⌘+2 to select second tab... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to your `real` question, which is a great idea — the answer is no, there isn't. (File an enhancement with Apple...!)

However: The keyboard shortcut for toggling to the next tab is Control-Tab, which I find quite easy to remember.

Also note that *all* keyboard shortcuts are user-configurable.